# \center and \centering

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I found that

```
\center
\begin{tabular}{...}
...
\end{tabular}
```

and

```
\centering
\begin{tabular}{...}
...
\end{tabular}
```

both make the following table centered.

My questions are:

1. Are `\center` and `\centering` the same? What is the difference between them?
2. Are they both commands? What are the scopes that they apply to?
   (note that in the examples, there are no `table` environment.)

Thanks!

Comment: I think `\center` is what happens "under the hood" when you call `begin{center}` (and on the other end, `\end{center}` shows up as `\endcenter`), while `\centering` just applies to the entire current scope. Thus, if I'm correct, you should either use `\centering` or the environment, but never `\center`. (The reason I'm writing this as a comment and not an answer is that I'm too uncertain, so don't shoot me if I'm wrong :P...)

Comment: @percusse: Are you sure `\center` and `\begin{center}` the same thing?

Comment: `\begin{center}...\end{center}` is more-or-less equivalent to `{\center...}`, so `\center` has a global effect whereas `\begin{center}...\end{center}` has a local effect.

Comment: Actually it is a weird artifact since in the plain TeX, you have `\command` and `\endcommand` syntax and by skipping lots of details it is the LaTeX version of `center` environment. See egreg's answer for more details. But I didn't claim it so anyway. There are lots of well-answered similar questions on this site please have a search on this site too and open a new question if they don't address your concerns.