# Overlapped Title and where to place the logo

Tags: titles

I have prepared the front page of the book but the title is overlapped and I need some more formatting like the title Web Blog to appear at the center(its not centered)  .And Where to put my college logo?

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\center
\textsc{\LARGE PONDICHERRY ENGINEERING COLLEGE}\\[1.5cm]
\textsc{\Large CASE TOOLS LABORATORY}\\[0.5cm]
\textsc{\large SOFTWARE REQUIREMENTS SPECIFICATION}\\[0.5cm]

\HRule \\[0.4cm]
{ \huge \bfseries WEB BLOG}\\[0.4cm]
\HRule \\[1.5cm]

\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
 \emph{Author:}\\
 Subham \textsc{Soni}
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
~
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushright}
\emph{Supervisor:}\\
\textsc{Mr.M. Thirumaran}
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}\\[4cm]

{\Large \today }\\[3cm]
\vfill
\end{titlepage}
\end{document![}][1]
```

[image]

Comment: the book class only. if scrbook is used to correct the error its ok

Comment: I hope this `\end{document![}][1]` is just a typo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this the expected result?

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\centering
{\LARGE\scshape PONDICHERRY ENGINEERING COLLEGE\\[1.5cm]}
{\Large\scshape CASE TOOLS LABORATORY\\[0.5cm]}
{\large\scshape SOFTWARE REQUIREMENTS SPECIFICATION\\[0.5cm]}

\HRule \\[0.4cm]
{\huge\bfseries WEB BLOG\\[0.4cm]}
\HRule \\[1.5cm]

\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
 \emph{Author:}\\
 Subham \textsc{Soni}
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
~
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushright}
\emph{Supervisor:}\\
\textsc{Mr.M. Thirumaran}
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}\\[4cm]

{\Large \today \\[3cm]}
\vfill
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

---

### EDIT

About the logo, I've downloaded the image http://www.pec.edu/images/pecemblem.png from the PEC site (hope they don't mind) and this is how you can insert the logo:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\centering

\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{pecemblem}\\[.5cm]

{\LARGE\scshape PONDICHERRY ENGINEERING COLLEGE\\[1.5cm]}
{\Large\scshape CASE TOOLS LABORATORY\\[0.5cm]}
{\large\scshape SOFTWARE REQUIREMENTS SPECIFICATION\\[0.5cm]}

\HRule \\[0.4cm]
{\huge\bfseries WEB BLOG\\[0.4cm]}
\HRule \\[1.5cm]

\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
 \emph{Author:}\\
 Subham \textsc{Soni}
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
~
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushright}
\emph{Supervisor:}\\
\textsc{Mr.M. Thirumaran}
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}\\[4cm]

{\Large \today \\[3cm]}
\vfill
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

---

### Some hints

- You have to use `\centering` and not `\center`. The latter is more or less equivalent to `\begin{center}` (see [\center and \centering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56334/27635) and the linked duplicate).
- The strange behavior with the overlapped title happens because when you change font attributes inside a group you have to terminate the paragraph otherwise it doesn't end (see for example [Incorrect line spacing when using \Large in a center environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53347/27635)). So encasing `\\[...]` in the group solves the problem.
- Since you are already using groups with braces like `{\Large ....}` it is better to use constructs like `{\Large\scshape ....}` rather than `\textsc{\Large ....}`.
- Nothing to say about `\end{document![}][1]` since it is obviously an error while you were trying to insert an image....