# Frame for a title page

Tags: tikz-pgf, titles, framed

The cover of  **Gonzalo Medina** from here : [Presentation Beamer [title page]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116077/presentation-beamer-title-page)  is beautiful and bright i tried to do it like him but in 
`\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}`  here is my try

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand\HRule{\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=2cm]{logo1}}
\titlegraphicii{\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=2cm]{logo2}}
\begin{center}

% Upper part of the page
\textsc{\LARGE University}\\[2.5cm]

\textsc{\Large Project}\\[3cm]

% Title
\HRule \\[0.4cm]
{ \huge \bfseries Title}\\[0.1cm]
{ \large \bfseries subTitle}\\[0.4cm]
\HRule \\[2cm]

\textsc{\normalsize Defended on : December day,year.}\\[1cm]

{\centering\itshape Jury Members\par}
President: president\par\medskip
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{\hspace{3pt}}p{.32\textwidth}@{}}
Examiners: & examiner 1 \\
& examiner 2 \\
& examiner 3 \\
& examiner 4
\end{tabular}%
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{\hspace{3pt}}p{.3\textwidth}@{}}
Supervisor 1: & supervisor \\
Supervisor 2: & supervisor
\end{tabular}%

\end{center}

\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

produce :
[image]
 I wonder if you could help me with that to get the same thing for document{report}

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Marc van Dongen the question i can't get the same thing i have some issue so I wonder if you could help me with this?

Comment: Maybe you should examine the [`titling`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titling) package. While trying to resemble stuff from `beamer` you might also benefit from `\usepackage{beamerarticle}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if you are looking for something like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

\newcommand\HRule{\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}

\newmdenv[%
    innertopmargin = 0.8cm,
    innerbottommargin = 0.8cm,
    backgroundcolor = blue,
    linewidth = 0pt,
    fontcolor = white
]{mybox}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=2cm]{logo1}\hfill\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=2cm]{logo2}

\begin{center}

% Upper part of the page
{\LARGE\scshape University\\[2.5cm]}

{\Large\scshape Project\\[3cm]}

% Title

\begin{mybox}
\centering
{\huge\bfseries Title\\[0.1cm]}
{\large\bfseries subTitle}
\end{mybox}

\vspace*{2cm}

{\normalsize\scshape Defended on : December day,year.\\[1cm]}

{\itshape Jury Members\\[1cm]}
{\raggedright President: president\par}
\bigskip
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{\hspace{3pt}}p{.3\textwidth}@{}}
Examiners: & examiner 1 \\
& examiner 2 \\
& examiner 3 \\
& examiner 4
\end{tabular}\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{\hspace{3pt}}p{.2\textwidth}@{}}
Supervisor 1: & supervisor \\
Supervisor 2: & supervisor
\end{tabular}%

\end{center}

\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

One thing: when changing font attributes like in

```
{\huge\bfseries Title}\\[0.1cm]
```

this has to be written as

```
{\huge\bfseries Title\\[0.1cm]}
```

otherwise the paragraph isn't ended and and this affects the baseline behavior.

For more info see, for example, this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/153699/27635) of mine and the related link.

Comment: Thanks but the jury members,examenirs  Examiners: & examiner 1, Supervisor 1: & supervisor are two small  and if possible those element be in the same order of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116077/presentation-beamer-title-page

Comment: @Educ I've edited the answer. See if now it's OK.

Comment: i update my question please check it

Comment: @Educ I don't know what you mean in the edited question. Since it seems to me to be a very different question, please remove the edit from this question and ask a new one.