# Frame for a title page 2

Tags: tikz-pgf, titles

In fact i'm working on that cover for my thesis  and i try to inspire from the beautiful  cover page of Mr Gonzalo Medina [Presentation Beamer [title page]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116077/presentation-beamer-title-page) and from Mr karlkoeller [Frame for a title page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154562/frame-for-a-title-page) but i can't manage

[image]

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand\HRule{\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

\center % Center everything on the page
\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=2cm]{logo1}\hfill
\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=2cm]{logo2}\par\vfill


% Upper part of the page
\textsc{\LARGE University}\\[2.5cm]

\textsc{\Large Project}\\[3cm]

% Title
\HRule \\[0.4cm]
{ \huge \bfseries Title}\\[0.1cm]
{ \large \bfseries subTitle}\\[0.4cm]
\HRule \\[2cm]

\textsc{\normalsize Defended on : December day,year.}\\[1cm]

\end{center}

\end{titlepage}
```

Comment: What does “can‘t manage” mean exactly? What do you want to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\centering

\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=2cm]{logo1}\hfill
\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=2cm]{logo2}\par\vfill

{\sffamily\small University of Science\par\vfill\vfill}

{\Large\bfseries THÈSE\par\vskip1em}

{\small pour obtenir le titre de\par\vskip0.5em}

{\large\bfseries Docteur en Sciences de l'Université Nice-Sophia Antipolis\par\vskip0.5em}

{\small Discipline : Mathématiques\par\vfill}

{\sffamily\small Presented by : Person\par\vfill}

\begin{minipage}{.9\textwidth}
\hrulefill\par\smallskip
\centering
{\bfseries
Équations différentielles stocastiques : resolubilité forte d'équations singulières dégénérées; analyse numérique de systèmes progressifs-rétrogrades de McKean-Vlason}
\par\vskip-.3\baselineskip
\hrulefill
\end{minipage}\par\vfill

{\small
Thèse dirigée par \textbf{Francois Delarue}\par\vskip0.5em

souteme le 6 décembre 2013\par\vskip1em

devant le jury composé par\par\vfill

\begin{tabular*}{12cm}{@{} l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} ll>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}r@{}}
M. & Cédric Bernardin & Examinateur & Profésseur des Universités \\
Mmme. & Cédric Bernardin & Examinateur & Directeur de Recherche INRA \\
M. & Cédric Bernardin & Examinateur & Profésseur des Universités \\
M. & Cédric Bernardin & Directeur & Profésseur des Universités \\
M. & Cédric Bernardin & Rapporteur & Directeur de Recherche INRA \\
M. & Cédric Bernardin & Rapporteur & Profésseur des Universités
\end{tabular*}
}

\vfill

\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Feel free to adjust the skips and the font sizes according to your needs.

Comment: Thank you so much for fixing That you're a real lifesaver!